# Install Windows 8 update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, debug, c#

I am creating a program in C# that uses Novation Launchpads, which are MIDI devices. Therefore I am using the functions `midiInNumDevs` and `midiOutNumDevs` and I am trying to make the program hotpluggable. However, I am running into the bug as explained by this part of Window's Knowledgebase:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2862818, which points to the update file https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2862768 that explains it includes what I think is my needed patch:

```
2862818 "midiInGetNumDevs" function returns incorrect number of MIDI input devices in Windows 8
```

However, I am not able to run the update on my Windows 10 machine (once upon a time it was Windows 8 before the built-in upgrade) as it complains that the update is not for my system, and I do not appear to be able to run it in compatibility mode either (there is no compatibility mode option in the properties for the file)

Any help as how to patch this or for a workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: Until Microsoft releases a patch for w10, there is nothing you can do unfortunately.

Comment: According to Microsoft (and that knowledgebase link) that bug doesn't exist in Windows 10, I'd contact them and let them know. For now perhaps you can get a patched version of the DLL from Windows 8 and import it into your project instead.